# NSUnkownException : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key piewTextField

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing my app for Deployment on ios5 with Xcode 4.6 .I have a singleview app i am creating simply a new objective-c class for a new View Controller
name **'PiewController'** i have defined the **PiewController.h** file like this:

[image: PiewController.h]

and my **PiewController.m** looks like this

[image: PiewController.m]

and my **PiewController.xib** Looks like this

[image: PiewController.xib]

and the connections of **File's Owner** are:

[image: Connections]

and the Error it is giving when i have loaded **PiewController** Directly from **AppDelegate**
[image]

**and the AppDelegate looks like**
[image]

Comment: First, your outlet property should be weak not strong. Second, in Interface Builder you need to tell it what subclass of UIViewController you are using.

Comment: i have tried weak it doesnt solve the issue and in interface builder the class is already set to **PiewController**

Comment: That isn't causing the issue. It is just something you need to change regardless of your issue.

Comment: alright thanks for that, i still cant figure why it is happening

Comment: Your appdelegate initializes PiewController using a class called "ViewController" and not "PiewController". `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PiewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Question, why are you making everything so hard for yourself? `ViewController`, `PiewController`, `piewTextField`... give things sensible names. I should know from the name what it does. What does `PiewController` do? No idea, I can only guess that it's a typo, except it isn't. What's wrong with `PhotoViewController` or `ProfileViewController`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm it seems you want to connect the PViewController's xib stuffs to the ViewController. The debug message, i think, can be interpreted as : there is no property like piewTextField in ViewController (which is true, since you defined it in pviewController). Are you sure you load the correct xib for pviewController and not for the default initialized ViewController in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: i have shown the app delegate now. i want the textfields value so i have to declare that in PiewController.h

Comment: But you alloc a viewController and assign a xib designed for a Piewcontroller, write : [[PiewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PiewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Turns Out i forgot to include PiewController in the AppDelegate
With the Following changes it works perfectly
[image]