# Swapping views inside a tabview controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an app based on a tabBar controller. Within a certain view I'd like to add swipe gesture recognition and swap the current view with another one (which is not part of the tabBarController array). I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
//Does not work
UIViewController *DesiredViewController =[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DesiredViewController" bundle:nil];
DesiredViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:DesiredViewController animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:DesiredViewController.view];
}
```

but the program crashes. The error I get is related to a SegmentedControl which is present in the next view but is absent in the current one. The views independently work perfectly!

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:'[<UIViewController 0xa355fb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X_SegmentedControl.'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.. I want to swap the views completely rather than putting one on top of each other. Any advice please? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406892/nsunkownexception-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-pie/16407010#16407010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about the transition.

You are loading a view controller from a NIB.

A view controller is usually subclassed, so (assuming that your nib is configured correctly and you have `.h` and `.m` implementation file for your DesiredViewController subclass) you should init like this:

```
DesiredViewController *controllerInstance =[[DesiredViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DesiredViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The exception is because you probably have a segmented control inside your view controller subclass, Xcode is trying to link this control to the outlet on the view controller, but this outlet doesn't exists (because you are allocating an `UIViewController` not the subclass).

Comment: Got it, thanks. I understand the mechanism now. Isn't there a way by which the old view could be completely ignored/removed? If the new one tries to link with the old one it is very risky. It's a calculator program and god knows what else could become linked between the two!

Answer (score 1):

instead use this

```
-(IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    DesiredViewController *objView =[[DesiredViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DesiredViewController" bundle:nil];
    objView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:objView animated:YES];
    [objView release]; // use release if using Non-ARC
}
```

Comment: Great, it does work, thanks! The problem however is that when the new view appears, this is on top of everything else and even on top of the tab bar.. So the tab bar becomes unusable.. How can I push it behind it?